# Cannot change the state of parent component and re-render

Tags: reactjs

im new to React, trying to make some simple 'Chat' app, stuck a bit in some feature.

im trying to make user list, that onClick (on one of the user) it will change the class (to active), and when hitting another user it will set the active class to the new user.

tried a lot of things, managed to make it active, but when hitting another user, the old one & the one receive the 'active' class.

here is my Parent componenet

```
class Conversations extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.loadConversations = this.loadConversations.bind(this);
    this.selectChat = this.selectChat.bind(this);

    this.state = { count: 0, selected: false, users: [] }
}

selectChat = (token) => {
    this.setState({ selected: token });
}

loadConversations = (e) => {
    $.get('/inbox/get_conversations', (data) => {
        let r = j_response(data);
        if (r) {
            this.setState({ count: r['count'], users: r['data']});
        }
    });
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    this.loadConversations();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.users.map((user) => {
                return(<User selectChat={this.selectChat} selected={this.state.selected} key={user.id} {...user} />)
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

here is my Child componenet

```
class User extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        token: this.props.token,
        selected: this.props.selected,
        username: this.props.username
    }

}

handleSelect = (e) => {
    //this.setState({selected: e.target.dataset.token});
    this.props.selectChat(e.target.dataset.token);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div data-selected={this.props.selected} className={'item p-2 d-flex open-chat ' + (this.props.selected == this.props.token ? 'active' : '')} data-token={this.props.token} onClick={(e) => this.handleSelect(e)}>
            <div className="status">
                <div className="online" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Online"></div>
            </div>
            <div className="username ml-3">
                {this.props.username}
            </div>
            <div className="menu ml-auto">
                <i className="mdi mdi-dots-horizontal"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Any help will be great...hope you can explain me why my method didnt work properly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `index` from `map` function to make element active.

Initially set `selected` to `0`;

```
this.state = { count: 0, selected: 0, users: [] }
```

Then pass index to child component,also make sure you render your `User` component when you are ready with data by adding a condition.

```
{this.state.users.length > 0 && this.state.users.map((user,index) => {
      return(<User selectChat={this.selectChat} selected={this.state.selected} key={user.id} {...user} index={index} />)
})}
```

In child component,

```
<div data-selected={this.props.selected} className={`item p-2 d-flex open-chat ${(this.props.selected === this.props.index ? 'active' : '')}`} data-token={this.props.token} onClick={() => this.handleSelect(this.props.index)}>
            ...
</div>
```

```
handleSelect  = (ind) =>{
  this.props.selectChat(ind);
}
```

Simplified [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v82egb) using List.

Comment: Hey, thanks. i tried it, but still cant make it work :( not sure what is wrong..is there a chance that the `componentDidMount` with the ajax killing it somehow?

Comment: In that case you need to conditionally render the User component, check the updated answer.

Comment: I did not use the 'full' solution. i just took out the idea how to make it work. i created in the 'users' object a new prop ('selected') and on click make sure to change it to true. while the rest selected props back to false.

Comment: Working perfectly. no errors at all ;) im still trying to play with it and try another ways. to better understand Raect